# How do i include an image file in json?

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I'm currently trying to send a POST request to my flask restful service that will generate a model to be saved to the database.
This model will include a url to an image that is hosted through cloudinary along with other data like date and name

My issue is that in Postman i'm only allowed to send `form-data` or `raw` which will include the json. I'm able to upload to cloudinary and receive the url needed, however i'm unable to get the json from the request so i'm unable to completely generate a model to be saved.

`image_json = request.get_json()` returns `None`

My question is if i'm only allowed to send one or the either `raw or form-data` How am i supposed to get the image and the corresponding data needed to save the model?

```
from cloudinary.uploader import upload
from cloudinary.utils import cloudinary_url
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import request
from models.image import ImageModel
from schemas.image import ImageSchema

image_schema = ImageSchema()
image_list_schema = ImageSchema(many=True)


class Image(Resource):
    @classmethod
    def post(cls):
        image_to_upload = request.files["image"]
        if image_to_upload:
            upload_result = upload(image_to_upload)
            url = cloudinary_url(upload_result['public_id'], format="jpg", crop="fill", width=100,height=100)[0]

            full_size_url = cloudinary_url(upload_result['public_id'], format="jpg", crop="fill", width=200, height=100, radius=20, effect="sepia")[0]

            image_json = request.get_json() # this returns None
            image_json["url"] = url
            image_json["full_size_url"] = full_size_url
            image = image_schema.load(image_json)

            try:
                image.save_to_db()
            except:
                return {"message": "error uploading file"}
            return image_schema.dump(image), 201
        return {"message": "no image uploaded"}, 401
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a file to flask using multipart/form-data, the file will be at request.files, so, in your case, it would be

```
image_json = request.files['here is the key you add to the file on postman']
```

The other stuffs, called form-data, will be at request.form. So, to get that:

```
form_data = request.form
```

So, using postman, when you select multipartm/form-data, you will first give a name for the file, and then you will select it. The name (or key) will be the key used in the dict to get the file, as explained above.
Also, for the form part, the key will work the same way